# Can't login via BasicAuth

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, token

I'm trying to implement oauth with token. Everything seems good, but after POST

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password
```

with set BasicAuth admin/admin (I have user in database with login admin and password admin)

I got window with basic auth, when i wrote my login and password I got again and again this window with basic auth.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("android-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client-credentials", "password","refresh_token")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_ANDROID_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000)
                .secret("android-secret").refreshTokenValiditySeconds(50000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
    }
}
```

.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    private PasswordEncoder encoder =
            PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(username -> {
            Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(username);
            if (user.isPresent()) {
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.get().getUsername(), encoder.encode(user.get().getPassword()),
                        true, true, true, true, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find the user '" + username + "'");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

**VERY IMPORTANT:**
if I remove ResourceServerConfig.java I can login via BasicAuth, after wrote admin/admin I got JSON from my localhost:8080 but I wanted access by token.

This is my 1st RESTful API.
Could anyone help me? Does anyone know where I made a mistake?
There is little information on the internet on the internet. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send your clientId: "android-client" and the secret "android-secret" as basic authentication credentials instead of your user (admin/admin) credentials which needs to be sent as http parameters (username=admin password = admin) like the "grant_type" parameter

so your request should be like this

> http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password**&username=admin&password=admin**

than add your clientId and secret to the basic authentication credentials